# Build Warning: Disabling subview autoresizing is not supported on iPhone OS versions prior to 3.0

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

This build warning just started showing up. I'm building for 3.1.3. Not sure what I did to trigger it. Anyone know what it means?!?

```
CompileXIB Classes/RootViewController.xib
Disabling subview autoresizing is not supported on iPhone OS versions prior to 3.0.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the Info button on your xib's main window, and set the Deployment Target to iPhone OS 3.0 or iPhone OS 3.1.

Edit: Images!

[image: Info Button]
[image: Deployment Target Popup]

(NB: These are from the 10.5 version of IB, but IIRC the 10.6 version is the same or close to it.)

Comment: Not sure if I'm finding/doing this right. I click on MainWindow.xib and then "Info" button in Xcode... I then get 3 tabs: General, Targets & Comments. None with option that I can find to "set Deployment Target to iPhone OS 3.0..." Also tried same thing with main project icon at top of Groups & Files list where I get many more options. Base SDK is already set at 3.0. Sry but sure what/where I should be looking...

Comment: Not the info button in Xcode, the info button in Interface Builder. :)

Comment: I didn't have the Info button in my toolbar by default. You can customize the toolbar to add it or directly open the Document Info view with Command + Option + I (or the menu: Window -> Document Info). Also, I had to do this for every xib it was complaining about, not sure the MainWindow.xib :(